# R - extract all strings matching pattern and create relational table

Tags: regex, r, dplyr

I am looking for a shorter and more pretty solution (possibly in tidyverse) to the following problem. I have a data.frame "data":

```
  id            string
1  A 1.001 xxx 123.123
2  B 23,45 lorem ipsum
3  C      donald trump
4  D    ssss 134, 1,45
```

What I wanted to do is to extract all numbers (no matter if the delimiter is "." or "," -> in this case I assume that string "134, 1,45" can be extracted into two numbers: 134 and 1.45) and create a data.frame "output" looking similar to this:

```
  id  string
1  A   1.001
2  A 123.123
3  B   23.45
4  C    <NA>
5  D     134
6  D    1.45
```

I managed to do this (code below) but the solution is pretty ugly for me also not so efficient (two for-loops). Could someone suggest a better way to do do this (preferably using dplyr)

```
# data
data <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                  string = c("1.001 xxx 123.123", 
                             "23,45 lorem ipsum", 
                             "donald trump", 
                             "ssss 134, 1,45"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# creating empty data.frame                     
len <- length(unlist(sapply(data$string, function(x) gregexpr("[0-9]+[,|.]?[0-9]*", x))))
output <- data.frame(id = rep(NA, len), string = rep(NA, len))

# main solution
start = 0

for(i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
  tmp_len <- length(unlist(gregexpr("[0-9]+[,|.]?[0-9]*", data$string[i])))
  for(j in (start+1):(start+tmp_len)){
    output[j,1] <- data$id[i]
    output[j,2] <- regmatches(data$string[i], gregexpr("[0-9]+[,|.]?[0-9]*", data$string[i]))[[1]][j-start]
  }
  start = start + tmp_len
}

# further modifications
output$string <- gsub(",", ".", output$string)
output$string <- as.numeric(ifelse(substring(output$string, nchar(output$string), nchar(output$string)) == ".",
                                   substring(output$string, 1, nchar(output$string) - 1),
                                   output$string))

output
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) Base R** This uses relatively simple regular expressions and no packages.

In the first 2 lines of code replace any comma followed by a space with a 
space and then replace all remaining commas with a dot.   After these two lines `s` will be: `c("1.001 xxx 123.123", "23.45 lorem ipsum", "donald trump", "ssss 134 1.45")`

In the next 4 lines of code trim whitespace from beginning and end of each string field and split the string field on whitespace producing a
list.   `grep` out those elements consisting only of digits and dots. (The regular expression `^[0-9.]*$` matches the start of a word followed by zero or more digits or dots followed by the end of the word so only words containing only those characters are matched.) Replace any zero length components with NA.  Finally add `data$id` as the names.  After these 4 lines are run the list `L` will be `list(A = c("1.001", "123.123"), B = "23.45", C = NA, D = c("134", "1.45"))` .

In the last line of code convert the list `L` to a data frame with the appropriate names.

```
s <- gsub(", ", " ", data$string)
s <- gsub(",", ".", s)

L <- strsplit(trimws(s), "\\s+")
L <- lapply(L, grep, pattern = "^[0-9.]*$", value = TRUE)
L <- ifelse(lengths(L), L, NA)
names(L) <- data$id

with(stack(L), data.frame(id = ind, string = values))
```

giving:

```
  id  string
1  A   1.001
2  A 123.123
3  B   23.45
4  C    <NA>
5  D     134
6  D    1.45
```

**2) magrittr** This variation of (1) writes it as a magrittr pipeline.

```
library(magrittr)

data %>%
     transform(string = gsub(", ", " ", string)) %>%
     transform(string = gsub(",", ".", string)) %>%
     transform(string = trimws(string)) %>%
     with(setNames(strsplit(string, "\\s+"), id)) %>%
     lapply(grep, pattern = "^[0-9.]*$", value = TRUE) %>%
     replace(lengths(.) == 0, NA) %>%
     stack() %>%
     with(data.frame(id = ind, string = values))
```

**3) dplyr/tidyr**  This is an alternate pipeline solution using dplyr and tidyr.  `unnest` converts to long form, `id` is made factor so that we can later use `complete` to recover id's that are removed by subsequent filtering, the filter removes junk rows and `complete` inserts NA rows for each `id` that would otherwise not appear.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(string = gsub(", ", " ", string)) %>%
  mutate(string = gsub(",", ".", string)) %>%
  mutate(string = trimws(string)) %>%
  mutate(string = strsplit(string, "\\s+")) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(id = factor(id))
  filter(grepl("^[0-9.]*$", string)) %>%
  complete(id)
```

**4) data.table**

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(data)
DT[, string := gsub(", ", " ", string)][, 
     string := gsub(",", ".", string)][,
     string := trimws(string)][,
     string := setNames(strsplit(string, "\\s+"), id)][,
     list(string = list(grep("^[0-9.]*$", unlist(string), value = TRUE))), by = id][,
     list(string = if (length(unlist(string))) unlist(string) else NA_character_), by = id]
DT
```

**Update** Removed assumption that junk words do not have digit or dot.  Also added (2), (3) and (4) and some improvements.

Comment: Unnest - this is the function I was looking for. Fantastic post - thank you! One question: what's the reason behind writing L <- strsplit(trimws(s), "\\s+"), instead of L <- strsplit(trimws(s), "\\s")?

Comment: "\\s" is ok if there is always one whitespace character -- wasn't sure.

Comment: Have made some improvements to (2) and (3).

Answer (score 2):

We can replace the `,` in between the numbers with `.` (using `gsub`), extract the numbers with `str_extract_all` (from `stringr` into a `list`), replace the `list` elements that have `length` equal to 0 with `NA`, set the names of the `list` with 'id' column, `stack` to convert the `list` to `data.frame` and rename the columns.

```
library(stringr)
setNames(stack(setNames(lapply(str_extract_all(gsub("(?<=[0-9]),(?=[0-9])", ".", 
      data$string, perl = TRUE), "[0-9.]+"), function(x) 
     if(length(x)==0) NA else as.numeric(x)), data$id))[2:1], c("id", "string"))
#  id  string
#1  A   1.001
#2  A 123.123
#3  B   23.45
#4  C      NA
#5  D     134
#6  D    1.45
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you be so kind and elaborate a bit more on "(?<=[0-9]),(?=[0-9])". I am not familiar with Perl-like notation

Comment: @user2280549  It is a lookaround that implies that a `,` is between two numbers

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. I was wondering what does "<=" or "=" mean before [0-9] in Perl notation

Comment: @user2280549 It is lookbehind and lookahead notation.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as Gabor's. I had hoped to use R's built-in parsing of strings (`type.convert`, used in `read.table`) rather than writing custom regex substitutions:

```
sp = setNames(strsplit(data$string, " "), data$id)

spc = lapply(sp, function(x) {
  x = x[grep("[^0-9.,]$", x, invert=TRUE)]

  if (!length(x))
    NA_real_
  else 
    mapply(type.convert, x, dec=gsub("[^.,]", "", x), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
})

setNames(rev(stack(spc)), names(data))

  id  string
1  A   1.001
2  A 123.123
3  B   23.45
4  C    <NA>
5  D     134
6  D    1.45
```

Unfortunately, `type.convert` is not robust enough to consider both decimal delimiters at once, so we need this `mapply` malarkey instead of `type.convert(x, dec = "[.,]")`.